# Generating single random sentences

Tags: packages, blindtext, lipsum

`lipsum`, `blindtext` and `kantlipsum` all seem to default to producing paragraphs, whereas I want them to generate individual sentences.  From the documentation, it looks as if it should be possible to make the `random` option in `blindtext` produce individual sentences, but I can't get that to work:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[random]{blindtext}
\setcounter{blindtext}{1}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I get

> Package blindtext Warning: Option random not defined for english

Now, the documentation on `random` does say:

> If the language does not support this option, the default text is used.

But it's a little surprising that it doesn't support English... am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following variant of `lipsum.sty` that will produce sentences instead of paragraphs; save the following file as `sentlipsum.sty` in your current working directory or in your local tree:

```
%%
%% This is file `sentlipsum.sty',
%% A small variation of 'lipsum.sty' originally written by Patrick Happel
%%
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{sentlipsum}[2012/12/16 v1.0 150 sentences of Lorem Ipsum dummy text]
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
\newcounter{sentlips@count}
\setcounter{sentlips@count}{0}

\ProcessOptions

\newcommand\sentlips@default{1-7}
\newcommand\setsentlipsumdefault[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\sentlips@default}{#1}}

\newcommand\sentlips@dosentlipsum{%
  \ifnum\value{sentlips@count}<\sentlips@max\relax%
    \addtocounter{sentlips@count}{1}%
    \csname sentlipsum@\roman{sentlips@count}\endcsname\ %
    \sentlips@dosentlipsum%
  \fi%
}

\newcommand\sentlipsum{\@sentlipsum}

\newcommand\@sentlipsum[1][\sentlips@default]{%
  \expandafter\sentlips@minmax\expandafter{#1}%
  \setcounter{sentlips@count}{\sentlips@min}%
  \addtocounter{sentlips@count}{-1}%
  \sentlips@dosentlipsum%
}

\def\sentlips@get#1-#2;{\def\sentlips@min{#1}\def\sentlips@max{#2}}
\def\sentlips@stripmax#1-{\edef\sentlips@max{#1}}
\def\sentlips@minmax#1{%
  \sentlips@get#1-\relax;%
  \edef\sentlips@tmpa{\sentlips@max}%
  \edef\sentlips@relax{\relax}%
  \ifx\sentlips@tmpa\sentlips@relax\edef\sentlips@max{\sentlips@min}%
  \else\expandafter\sentlips@stripmax\sentlips@max\fi%
}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@i{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
  adipiscing elit.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@ii{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales,
  sollicitudin vel, wisi.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@iii{Nulla malesuada porttitor diam.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@iv{Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@v{Fusce mauris et vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@vi{Ut lorem lorem, interdum
  eu, tincidunt sit amet, laoreet vitae, arcu.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@vii{In hac habitasse platea
  dictumst.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@viii{Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
  et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@ix{Morbi luctus, wisi viverra faucibus pretium,
  nibh est placerat odio, nec commodo wisi enim eget quam.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@x{Suspendisse vitae elit.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xi{Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
  magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xii{Fusce facilisis lacinia dui.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xiii{Nullam elementum, magna in cursus sodales, augue est scelerisque sapien, venenatis congue nulla arcu et pede.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xiv{Etiam ac leo a risus tristique nonummy.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xv{Praesent eros nulla, congue
  vitae, euismod ut, commodo a, wisi.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xvi{Nulla mattis luctus nulla.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xvii{Curabitur tellus magna, porttitor a, commodo
  a, commodo in, tortor.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xviii{Donec et nisl at wisi luctus bibendum.  Nam
  interdum tellus ac libero.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xix{Nulla non mauris vitae wisi posuere convallis.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xx{Nullam urna nulla, ullamcorper
  in, interdum sit amet, gravida ut, risus.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxi{Etiam pede massa, dapibus vitae, rhoncus in,
  placerat posuere, odio.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxii{Etiam suscipit aliquam arcu.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxiii{Donec et nisl id sapien blandit mattis.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxiv{Vestibulum pharetra nulla
  at lorem.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxv{Vivamus eu tellus sed tellus consequat
  suscipit.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxvi{Duis aliquet dui in est.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxvii{Donec vel nibh ut felis consectetuer laoreet.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxviii{Donec molestie, magna ut luctus ultrices,
  tellus arcu nonummy velit, sit amet pulvinar elit justo et mauris.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxix{Cras dapibus, augue quis scelerisque
  ultricies, felis dolor placerat sem, id porta velit odio eu elit.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxx{Sed mattis, erat sit amet gravida malesuada,
  elit augue egestas diam, tempus scelerisque nunc nisl vitae libero.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxxi{Sed consequat tellus et tortor.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxxii{Duis malesuada interdum
  arcu.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxxiii{Sed eleifend, eros sit amet faucibus
  elementum, urna sapien consectetuer mauris, quis egestas leo justo
  non risus.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxxiv{Nullam eleifend justo in nisl.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxxv{Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
  torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxxvi{Nulla malesuada risus ut urna.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxxvii{Donec tempus neque vitae est.  Aenean egestas
  odio sed risus ullamcorper ullamcorper.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxxviii{Fusce suscipit cursus sem.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xxxix{Praesent sed neque id pede mollis rutrum.}

\newcommand\sentlipsum@xl{Sed gravida lectus ut purus.}

\newcommand\lipsum@xli{Vivamus non justo in dui mattis posuere.}

\newcommand\lipsum@xlii{In suscipit mauris a
  dolor pellentesque consectetuer.}

\newcommand\lipsum@xliii{Maecenas accumsan dapibus sapien.}

\newcommand\lipsum@xliv{Phasellus fringilla, metus id feugiat
  consectetuer, lacus wisi ultrices tellus, quis lobortis nibh lorem
  quis tortor.}

\newcommand\lipsum@xlv{Cras egestas ipsum a nisl.}

\newcommand\lipsum@xlvi{Vivamus fringilla, enim et commodo
  malesuada, tortor metus elementum ligula, nec aliquet est sapien ut
  lectus.}

\newcommand\lipsum@xlvii{Vivamus ante ante, mattis laoreet, posuere eget, congue vel, nunc.}

\newcommand\lipsum@xlviii{Quisque posuere metus viverra pede.}

\newcommand\lipsum@xlix{Vivamus augue purus, laoreet in, scelerisque vel,
  commodo id, wisi.}

\newcommand\lipsum@l{Quisque facilisis auctor sapien.}

\newcommand\lipsum@li{Aliquam volutpat auctor lorem et cras placerat est vitae lectus.}

\newcommand\lipsum@lii{Suspendisse porta fermentum mauris.}

\newcommand\lipsum@liii{Phasellus placerat vulputate quam.}

\newcommand\lipsum@liv{Maecenas ultrices mi
  sed diam.}

\newcommand\lipsum@lv{Nullam elit sapien, eleifend eu,
  commodo nec, semper sit amet, elit.}

\newcommand\lipsum@lvi{Morbi tincidunt posuere arcu.}

\newcommand\lipsum@lvii{Nunc interdum elementum urna.}

\newcommand\lipsum@lviii{Nulla sit amet nisl at
  sapien egestas pretium.}

\newcommand\lipsum@lix{Nunc tincidunt, risus quis bibendum
  facilisis, lorem purus rutrum neque, nec porta tortor urna quis
  orci.}

\newcommand\lipsum@lx{Vestibulum in leo eu erat tristique mattis.}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `sentlipsum.sty'.
```

The main command is `\sentlipsum` and it behaves in a fashion similar to `\lipsum` (from the `lipsum` package): `\sentlipsum` produces seven sentences; `\sentlipsum[<number>]`, where `<number>` is an integer between 1 and 60 produces the sentence whose number corresponds to `<number>`, and `\sentlipsum[<number1>-<number2>]` produces `<number2>-<number1>+1` sentences, starting from the one associated to `<number1>` and ending with the one associated to `<number2>` (again, both numbers must be integers between 1 and 60).

```
\documentclass[parskip=full+]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{sentlipsum}

\begin{document}

\sentlipsum

\sentlipsum[1]

\sentlipsum[23-26]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I only used `scratcl` and the `parfill=full*` option to quickly get a visual separation between paragraphs for the example.

Comment: It looks like you put in a lot of work to get that working... I feel rather bad about saying that the main point was to be able to use an `ipsum` variant in a compact MWE.

Comment: @Mohan in fact, I will be using this new variant a lot since I often need sentences instead of whole paragraphs for some of my answers and test codes, so the time used (it was not much, by the way) was well spent ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sentence generator based on `kantlipsum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\kantsentences}{ O{1} m }
 {
  \kgl_sentences:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \kgl_sentences:nn #1 #2
 {
  \group_begin:
   \cs_set_eq:NN \kgl_number:n \use_none:n
   \cs_set_eq:NN \kgl_par: \prg_do_nothing:
   \tl_gclear:N \g_tmpa_tl
   \prg_replicate:nn { #2/5 + 1 }
    {
     \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \g_kgl_pars_seq {#1} }
     \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_tmpa_tl { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
     \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_tl { ~ }
    }
  \group_end:
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq {.} \g_tmpa_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ##1 } .\par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{Four sentences}

\kantsentences{4}

\section{Nine sentences}

\kantsentences[10]{9}

\end{document}
```

I use the fact that generally the Kantian paragraphs consist of seven sentences. So I divide the requested number by five and add one, then I gather this number of Kantian paragraphs in a unique token list, from which I extract the requested number of sentences.

The optional argument to `\kantsentences` is the initial Kantian paragraph (default 1).

[image]